# How to Chaining html() and text() together on same element

Tags: jquery

I wanted to render some element as html and some as text. e.g `{h1}hii{h1}` has to be in text but `<br>` has to render as html.

I tried to chain `.hmtl().text()`

```
var str = "{h}hii{/h};
this.text(str).html("<br/>");
```

It overlapping one element with another if i changed the sequence.
consider < as { and > as }

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here. Could you please give a much clearer description, and example the output you're trying to create.

Comment: <div id="data"></div> $('#data').html("<h1>should apply html h1 prop and font get bigger</h1>").text("<h1>should print as it is with it's tag</h1>"); this what i am trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close that string then put it in the html or, based on the comment...
Not 100% where you want the `<br />` either IN the head or after it so I show both

```js
var str = "hii";
$('#data').append("<h1>I am in the head</h1>");
$('#data').find('h1').append("<br/>").append(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="data"></div>
I am after the heading
```

```js
var str = "hii";
$('#data').append("<h1>I am in the head</h1>");
$('#data').find('h1').html(str).after("<br/>");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="data"></div>
I am after the heading
```

Comment: Ya but it will render <br/> as html . but here i wanted to print as it is. so for that it is possible to do like this.html(str).text("<br>") ?